# How to union same table in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, union

Now I have the following sql:

```
SELECT MAX(a), MIN(a)
FROM t1 join t2 join t3
UNION ALL 
SELECT MAX(b), MIN(b)
FROM t1 join t2 join t3
UNION ALL 
SELECT MAX(c), MIN(c)
FROM t1 join t2 join t3
UNION ALL 
SELECT MAX(d), MIN(d)
FROM t1 join t2 join t3
```

While table t1, t2, t3 are all huge, join them is very slow.

How can I join them just once in this query? Alias the table or create a temp table(query scope)?

And

1. I don't want to transform them into 1 row 4 column.
2. I tried to create view. It doesn't work.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't think you can improve the structure of your query, but you could consider tuning the query by adding indices to the join columns.

Comment: Your query doesn't specify any join conditions. What is T1, T2 and T3 really about?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen It joined the table 4 times. I think it must can be improved. The table has 10M records, it has indices already.

Comment: @Dai It has join conditions, But it doesn't matter, the four from caluse are same.

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server, you can use a lateral join:

```
SELECT v.x
FROM t1 join
     t2
     on . . . join
     t3
     on . . . cross apply
     (values (a), (b), (c), (d)) v(x);
```

Comment: Thank you. But I forget note that I select aggregation result (sum(a), sum(b), sum(c)), does it works?

Comment: @DeanXu . . . This answers the question that you asked.  If you have another question, ask *another* question, including appropriate tags and sample data.  If you change *this* question, you might invalidate this answer, which would draw downvotes.

Comment: OK. I change my question and I use MySQL. Is there a solution in mysql?